# ButterKnife error: cannot find symbol method bind(MyActivity)

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, butterknife

I recently switched to ButterKnife version 7.0.1 and I keep getting this error. It points to this part of the code:

Here's the exact part of the code:

```
public class SupportedBanksActivity extends AppCompatActivity {


 @Bind(R.id.activity_supported_banks_lv)
    ListView mListView;

@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_supported_banks);
        ButterKnife.bind(this);
    }
}
```

and the error:

error: cannot find symbol method bind(SupportedBanksActivity)

I don't understand why it says that. I can go into this method of the ButterKnife library and I see that's it's there. I have made the following changes to my code:

build.gradle

```
lintOptions {
  disable 'InvalidPackage'
}

packagingOptions {
  exclude 'META-INF/services/javax.annotation.processing.Processor'
}

dependencies {
    compile 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:7.0.1'
}
```

proguard-rules.txt

```
-keep class butterknife.** { *; }
-dontwarn butterknife.internal.**
-keep class **$$ViewBinder { *; }

-keepclasseswithmembernames class * {
    @butterknife.* <fields>;
}

-keepclasseswithmembernames class * {
    @butterknife.* <methods>;
}
```

Comment: `Butterknife` has a uppercase K. Is it right in your code?

Comment: Please check the uppercase and edit your question if needed

Comment: @DeividiCavarzan yep, it's uppercase K

Comment: Is your Activity declared in the Manifest??

Comment: Please post the code from your Activity

Comment: @Coeus Yep, it's declared in the manifest

Comment: @fractalwrench just did

Comment: Did you try with "Invalidate/Restart Cache" ?

Comment: @Coeus Yep, multiple times. It seems to me though that the problem lies in ButterKnife somehow not recognizing my Activity as an Activity. It says 'cannot find symbol method bind(SupportedBanksActivity )'  so as far as I understand it thinks that SupportedBanksActivity does not extend Activity

Comment: @nsmirosh Mmmm then try to extends your activity from AppCompatActivity

Comment: @Coeus tried it, but still no result

Comment: You do not have any field with bind annotated - this might be the problem

Comment: @ligi Sorry, didn't post the full code. There are actually annotated methods with '@Bind'

Comment: which is your Butterknife's version?

Comment: @Coeus 7.0.1 is shown in the question

Comment: @nsmirosh what is shown when you auto-complete in AS after ButterKnife ?

Comment: @ligi just regular ButterKnife methods : bind, apply, etc..

Comment: If there is no problem its just a suggestion try removing AppCOmpatActivity and just add Activity in it

Comment: @Hardy tried it, but it didn't help unfortunately

Answer (score 0):

Hello i have used butterknife example and my gradle file didn't contain your lines having in your gradle file so may be that could be the issue try

**removing below lines from it :->**

```
lintOptions {


 disable 'InvalidPackage'

}

packagingOptions {
  exclude 'META-INF/services/javax.annotation.processing.Processor'
}
```